# Kubectl drain node failed: "Forbidden: node updates may only change labels, taints, or capacity"

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, azure-aks

When attempting to drain a node on an AKS K8s cluster using:

```
kubectl drain ${node_name} --ignore-daemonsets
```

I get the following error:

```
   "The Node \"aks-agentpool-xxxxx-0\" is invalid: []: Forbidden: node updates may only change labels, taints, or capacity (or configSource, if the DynamicKubeletConfig feature gate is enabled)"
```

Is there something extra that needs to be done on AKS nodes to allow draining?

(Context: This is part of an automation script I'm writing to drain a kubernetes node for maintenance operations without downtime, so the draining is definitely a prerequisite here)

An additional troubleshooting note:

This command is being run via Ansible's "shell" module, but when the command is run directly in BASH, it works fine.

Further, the ansible is being run via a Jenkins pipeline. Debug statements seem to show:

- the command being correctly formed and executed.
- the context seems correct (so kubeconfig is accessible)
- pods can be listed (so kubeconfig is active and correct)

Comment: According to `kubectl node drain`:  

```
If there are any pods that are neither mirror pods nor managed by ReplicationController, ReplicaSet, DaemonSet, StatefulSet or Job, then drain will not delete any pods unless you use --force.  --force will also allow deletion to proceed if the managing resource of one or more pods is missing.
```

Thus, `kubectl node drain #{node_name} --force` should work. Otherwise you might not have permissions to do that.

Comment: This time I tried with the --force flag, still same error though: ``` "stderr": "The Node \"aks-agentpool-0010101-0\" is invalid: []: Forbidden: node updates may only change labels, taints, or capacity (or configSource, if the DynamicKubeletConfig feature gate is enabled)"``` ... If it's permissions, how would I check this ?

Answer (score 1):

> This command is being run via Ansible's "shell" module, but when the
>   command is run directly in BASH, it works fine.
>
> Further, the ansible is being run via a Jenkins pipeline.

It's good that you added this information because it totally changes the perspective from which we should look at the issue you experience.

**For debugging purposes instead of running your command, try to run:**

```
kubectl auth can-i drain node --all-namespaces
```

both directly in `bash shell` as well as via **Ansible's** `shell module`

It should at least give you an answer if this is not a permission issue.

Other commands that you may use to debugging in this case are:

```
ls -l .kube/config

cat .kube/config

whoami
```

Last one to make sure that **Ansible** uses the same `user`. If you already know that it uses different `user`, try to run the script as the same `user` you use for running it in a **bash shell**.

Once you check this, we can continue the debugging process.

Comment: Hi Mario, thanks for this useful info. So via the pipeline+ansible check I get a "yes" ```    "stdout": "Checking can I drain ? yes", 
    "stdout_lines": [
        "Checking can I drain ? yes"
    ]```   and via bash I also get a "yes". I'm also specifying the direct path to bash in Ansible's shell module via args to be sure it's not shell-specific behaviour.

Comment: ok, so it looks more complicated than I thought. Is your `Jenkins` set up outside the cluster or is it part of it ? And ansible ? What is the authentication method used with your AKS cluster ? Is it just pure RBAC or Azure AD integrated one ?